# Execute field values as SQL in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Suppose that we have a table with a field e.g. SqlStateMent
How do I execute all the statements?

My real problem is that I am trying to insert all the tables into one table, I know how to get name of all the tables, and make sql statements. I don't want to just execute the statements, but to make the commands first and keep them in a table, then execute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL statement is a string. A VBA variable can be set to the SQL statement string and then the variable can be referenced as if referencing the statement directly. Referencing a field that holds an SQL statement string is like referencing a VBA variable.

However, only action SQL statements (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT) can be 'executed'. SELECT SQL statements can be referenced to open a recordset object or to set a RecordSource or RowSource property.

So, assume the SQL statement saved in the field is 
`DELETE FROM tablename` 
and textbox or combobox or listbox on form is bound to that field. The SQL statement can be executed with code behind that form:
`CurrentDb.Execute Me!fieldname`
`CurrentDb.Execute Me.controlname`
That code will take field or control value from record that has focus.

Why do you need to do this? Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is using Access in a homoiconic fashion.

Comment: That's a new word for me. I looked it up and have no idea what to do with it. Did a minor edit on my answer. Good luck with your effort.

Comment: The idea is simple, Imagine Command Pattern where you store the commands and then execute them in a language, now we try to do the same thing in Sql, part of the language becomes data to be executed when needed. It is that simple